# Retrieve live information from alternate source

Tags: html, curl

I currently work for a company that sells TV's and have created a webpage that displays each model sold with an up to date price list. This is because I download the source, get the price and update the list with a C++ application I created.

Anyway I need to retrieve whether an item is in stock on a webpage that uses location to check. So it has to be done on the site itself and not when I retrieve the information on my end.

Is there any way of taking data from a specific url?

I've done some research into cURL but not sure if that's what I need in this situation.

Comment: Youre on the right track. I've used curl + regex to glean information in a web page from a URL. You just have to know the exact URL, and what page content you want to find.  For instance, you know to look at www.example.com/product123 and you know you want to check whether or not the `<div class="out-of-stock">` exists.

Comment: Oh great, and yes I have the code im looking for (   id="delivery" class="home-delivery home-delivery- available">  ) and the exact url list

Comment: Im wondering, if theres a way to get a post code by location and enter it to retrieve whether for example "http://www.currys.co.uk/gbuk/tv-and-home-entertainment/televisions/televisions/lg-oled55c7v-55-smart-4k-ultra-hd-hdr-oled-tv-10160548-pdt.html" that TV is in stock. I want to then print that on my own webpage next to the prices if that makes sense

Comment: Sounds like new question material. Probably 2 other questions. Not sure what's meant by post code.

Comment: True I am wondering, forget about the post codes problem for another day, when it comes to using cURL is that what will help me search a url for specific code

Comment: EXAMPLE : id="delivery" class="home-delivery home-delivery- available"

Comment: Search a web page for specific string*. Yes, like I said, use curl to get the entire plaintext page contents of the URL. Then use regex to filter for the info you need. If you're using Linux cli, you could pipe the curl statement into a grep call, in which you have your regex query which will filter the data accordingly and only return the data which is relevant to you.